# UINavigationItem title truncation

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I have text that is built from two Strings:
A(B)

I want to use both strings as the title for the UINavigationItem but in case of truncation I want only A to be truncated and not B.

Example:
The title I want is **"The quick brown fox jumps (over the lazy dog)"**.
The screen size is too small so the title truncates and it is now **"The quick brown fox jumps (over..."**.

What I want it to be is: **"The quick br... (over the lazy dog)"**

How can I do that?

Comment: It would help if you can provide some more context to the question, what are you trying to do. Show us some code please.

Comment: It would be better if you explain more...

Comment: Added and example

Comment: one of the solution is added label on navigation bar and use "Truncated Middle" Property of Label to obtain desire output.

Answer (score 1):

First check number of characters navigation bar allowing as title without truncating. Next, before setting title check whether the total string length is less than those number of characters or not. Now based on condition set either combined string or B only.

Comment: how can I check the number of characters navigation bar allowing?

Comment: By default it allows maximum 28 characters. It's better to check length of title string should be less than 18 characters

Comment: It allows 28 characters on every screen size?

Comment: Yes. It will if there are no right bar button and left bar buttons. If any bar button present, you have to exclude those buttons width.

Answer (score 1):

Since xcode won't be able to detect in which part of your title you want to stop and which part you want to start again, you need to do it yourself.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.navigationItem.title = "Heal the world make it a better place for you and for me and the entire human race"
    setNavTitle(title: self.navigationItem.title!)
}

func setNavTitle(title: String)
{
    //get the last 10 characters of your title, change the number to your need
    let last10 = title.substring(from:title.index(title.endIndex, offsetBy: -14))

    //get the first 10 characters of your title, change the number to your need
    let first10 = title.substring(to: title.index(title.startIndex, offsetBy: 14))

    //concatenate the strings
    let title = first10 + " ... " + last10
    self.navigationItem.title = title
}
```

Comment: the problem with this code is that it is not always 10 characters. it is changes based on the screen size.

Comment: get the screen size ( CGFloat width = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width; ), from there adjust your title length to your need